Error in eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE) : non-square matrix in 'eigen' in Gibbs sampler
So I've inherited a dpmm project in R, and I'm trying to understand the code. Its throwing an:

"Error in eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE) : non-square matrix in
'eigen' error".

I've tried to debug it myself, but I've honestly gotten stuck. I've tried reading on some of the other answers to the question, but part of my issue is that I don't understand why the error is coming in the first place. Can someone walk me through it? I don't see a good explanation for the error in this code, nor could I find an explanation for why code like mine would produce this error.
alpha <- 0.001
num_iter <- 100
library(MASS)
set.seed(123)
num_samples <- 1000
true_k <- 3
true_means <- matrix(rnorm(true_k*2, mean = 0, sd = 3), ncol = 2)
true_variances <- rep(1, true_k)
true_weights <- rep(1/true_k, true_k)
cluster_assignments <- sample(true_k, num_samples, replace = TRUE, prob = true_weights)
data <- matrix(0, nrow = num_samples, ncol = 2)
for (i in 1:true_k) {
  data[cluster_assignments == i,] <- t(mvrnorm(sum(cluster_assignments == i), true_means[i,], diag(true_variances[i],2)))
}

dpmm_gibbs_sampling <- function(data, alpha, num_iter) {
    num_samples <- nrow(data)
    num_dimensions <- ncol(data)
    num_clusters <- 1
    cluster_means <- matrix(0, nrow = num_samples, ncol = num_dimensions)
    # Initialize cluster_variances with square matrices
    cluster_variances <- vector("list", num_clusters)
    for (k in 1:num_clusters) {
      cluster_variances[[k]] <- diag(var(data))
    }
    assignments <- rep(1, num_samples)
    
    for (iter in 1:num_iter) {
      for (i in 1:num_samples) {
        old_cluster <- assignments[i]
        if (old_cluster <= num_clusters) {
          cluster_means[old_cluster, ] <- cluster_means[old_cluster, ] - data[i, ] / table(assignments)[old_cluster]
        } 
        data_count <- table(assignments)[old_cluster] - 1
        if (data_count == 0) {
          cluster_means <- cluster_means[-old_cluster, , drop = FALSE]
          cluster_variances <- cluster_variances[-old_cluster]
          # Update assignments
          assignments <- assignments - (assignments > old_cluster)
          # Update num_clusters
          num_clusters <- num_clusters - 1
        } else {
          cluster_means[old_cluster, ] <- cluster_means[old_cluster, ] - data[i, ] / data_count
        }
        prob_existing_clusters <- rep(0, num_clusters)
        for (j in 1:num_clusters) {
          prob_existing_clusters[j] <- log(table(assignments)[j]) +
            dmvnorm(data[i,], cluster_means[j,], cluster_variances[[j]])
        }
        prob_new_cluster <- log(alpha) - (1/2) * sum(log(diag(cluster_variances[[1]]))) - (1/2) *
          t(data[i, ]) %*% solve(cluster_variances[[1]]) %*% data[i,]
        prob_existing_clusters <- exp(prob_existing_clusters - max(prob_existing_clusters))
        probs <- c(prob_existing_clusters, prob_new_cluster)
        probs <- probs / sum(probs)
        new_cluster <- sample(c(1:num_clusters, num_clusters + 1), prob = probs)
        assignments[i] <- new_cluster
        if (new_cluster >  num_clusters) {
          num_clusters <- num_clusters + 1
          cluster_means <- rbind(cluster_means, matrix(0, nrow = 1, ncol = num_dimensions))
          cluster_means[new_cluster, ] <- data[i,]
          cluster_variances[[new_cluster]] <- diag(var(data))
        } else {
          cluster_means[new_cluster,] <- cluster_means[new_cluster,] + data[i,] / table(assignments)[new_cluster]
          cluster_variances[[new_cluster]] <- sum((data[assignments == new_cluster,] -
                                                     cluster_means[new_cluster,])^2 + 1) /
            (table(assignments)[new_cluster] + 1) * diag(num_dimensions)
        }
        print(dim(cluster_variances[[1]]))
      }
   }
}

I have tried several things. I changed how cluster_variances was initialized, but that did not solve the issue. I can localize the issue to this line
prob_existing_clusters[j] <- log(table(assignments)[j]) + 
     dmvnorm(data[i, ], cluster_means[j, ], cluster_variances[[j]]) 

I also tried to make my own dmvnorm function which didn't help.
I'm expecting this function to work as a dirichlet process mixture model with a gibbs sampler.

The problem seems to be with the cluster_variances[[k]] <- diag(var(data)) statement. var(data) is already a diagonal 2x2 matrix. diag() simply extracts the diagonal elements, so is a vector of length 2. You are sending it to dmvnorm as if it is a matrix. I guess the solution might well be to replace the statement with cluster_variances[[k]] <- var(data).
